# What is wrong with my function to find the mean of a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I know there is an easier way to find the mean of a list without using a for loop but in this circumstance I need to write a function using a for loop to find the mean.

```
myOddList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def meanCalculator(myOddList):
    sumOfNumbers = 0
    for i in myOddList:
        sumOfNumbers += i
        mean = sumOfNumbers / (len(myOddList))
        return mean
    
mean = meanCalculator(myOddList)
print(mean)
```

When I run this code instead of getting 3, I get 0.2, so I know this all looks really simple but I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since in Python you have to define when the loop begins and ends by indentation, when you return the mean how are doing it currently:

```
myOddList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def meanCalculator(myOddList):
    sumOfNumbers = 0
    for i in myOddList:
        sumOfNumbers += i
        mean = sumOfNumbers / (len(myOddList))
        return mean <------- this stops the for loop at the first iteration
                             and  returns 1 / (len(myOddList)) = 0.2
    
mean = meanCalculator(myOddList)
print(mean)
```

But if you do it in the following it works as expected:

```
myOddList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def meanCalculator(myOddList):
    sumOfNumbers = 0
    for i in myOddList:
        sumOfNumbers += i
        mean = sumOfNumbers / (len(myOddList))
    return mean <------- this way you return the mean only once the 
                         for loop is complete and you have found the sum
                         of all the numbers in the array

mean = meanCalculator(myOddList)
print(mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the mean within the for loop. It reaches the first number 1, and divides it by 5 returning 0.2

```
myOddList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def meanCalculator(myOddList):
    sumOfNumbers = 0
    for i in myOddList:
        sumOfNumbers += i
        mean = sumOfNumbers / (len(myOddList))

    return mean
    
mean = meanCalculator(myOddList)
print(mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```py
def meanCalculator(myOddList):
    sumOfNumbers = 0
    for i in myOddList:
        sumOfNumbers =i+sumOfNumbers
        mean = sumOfNumbers / (len(myOddList))
    return mean
    
mean = meanCalculator(myOddList)
print(mean)
```

You must be outside the loop --->return mean

Answer (score 0):

Add up all the numbers, then return the mean outside the `for` loop.  No need to compute the mean inside the `for` loop until the sum is complete, and you don't want the `return` in the `for` loop or it stops on the first number.  `+=` is another optimization.

```
def meanCalculator(myOddList):
    sumOfNumbers = 0
    for i in myOddList:
        sumOfNumbers += i
    return sumOfNumbers / len(myOddList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an indentation issue to me, some of the other lines are over indented:

```
myOddList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def meanCalculator(myOddList):
    sumOfNumbers = 0
    for i in myOddList:
        sumOfNumbers += i

    # Should be outside the loop since
    # It doesn't really make sense to keep computing the mean for every iteration of the loop
    mean = sumOfNumbers / (len(myOddList))
    return mean
    
mean = meanCalculator(myOddList)
print(mean)
```

Also you should be able to use the built-in [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to compute the sum of your array

```
def meanCalculator(myOddList):
    sumOfNumbers = sum(myOddList)
    mean = sumOfNumbers / len(myOddList)
    return mean
    
myOddList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mean = meanCalculator(myOddList)
print(mean)
```